# I want to add points only if the first button clicked was the correct answer, and not add points if the first button I clicked was a wrong answer

Tags: swift3

I want to add points only if the first button clicked was the correct answer, and not add points if the first button I clicked was a wrong answer. Can someone tell me how to do that please?
 This code shown here adds points even though the first answer that has been chosen is the wrong answer.

```
var currentQuestion = 0
var rightAnswerPlacement:UInt32 = 0
var points = 0

@IBOutlet weak var lbl: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var correctornot: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var numberOfPoints: UILabel!

@IBAction func next(_ sender: Any) {
    newQuestion()
    correctornot.text = ""
}
var firstTimePressed = true
@IBAction func action(_ sender: AnyObject) {
    if (sender.tag == Int(rightAnswerPlacement)) {
        print("Correct")
        correctornot.text = "correct"

        if firstTimePressed {
            points += 1
            firstTimePressed = false
        } else{
            points += 0
        }
    } else {
        print("Wrong")
        correctornot.text = "false"
        if firstTimePressed{
            points -= 1
            firstTimePressed = false
        } else{
            points += 0
        }
    }
    numberOfPoints.text = "\(points)"
}

override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    newQuestion()
}
```

Comment: Please elaborate what is wrong. Are you sure the tags are set up correctly? Is the correct branch of the if statement executed?

Comment: If the chosen answer is not equal to the rightAnswerPlacement, then it is wrong.

Comment: So `sender.tag == Int(rightAnswerPlacement)` evaluates to true regardless of which button you choose and what is the value of `rightAnswerPlacement`? Btw why would you declare `rightAnswerPlacement` as `UInt32`? And please also include the code where you assign tags to your buttons.

Comment: There are arrays of questions and answers before this code and I assigned the rightAnswerPlacement to the answers. There are three buttons and I assigned them the tags of 1, 2, 3.

Comment: It is UInt32 because I had to use it n another code.